# how to unwind multiple collections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

my query returns rows of the form:

```
node | {node1, node2, node3} | {float1, float2, float3}
```

i would like to unwind the two collections which always have the same number of elements, so that i will get rows of the form:

```
node | node1 | float1
node | node2 | float2
node | node3 | float3
```

i tried to unwind both collections but that will return all permutations of the elements, so in this case 9 rows.

is there a simple way to achieve this using cypher?

Comment: Can you post the whole query please?  It could be there's a better way to go about it rather than to try what you're asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example. It gets a collection of `Nodes` and a collection of `Floats`. Then it iterates though the size of the collection and dumps them out in tabular form.  No attention to sorting ans an assumption that they are the same size collection.

```
MATCH (m:Top)-->(n:Float)
WITH m, collect(n.name) AS float
MATCH (m)-->(n:Node)
WITH m, float, collect(n.name) AS node, range(0,size(float)-1,1) AS coll_size
WHERE size(float) = size(node)
UNWIND coll_size AS idx
RETURN m.name, float[idx], node[idx]
```

Here is a sample of the output.

[image]

Comment: thanks, that was it! i think size() should be length() though.

Comment: The `length` function is for paths. `size` is for collections.